# For library project in Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0, Version properties not working

Tags: android, gradle

For the latest Android Gradle plugin(4.1.0), BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME not working in the library module. But it's working fine for the application module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0, Version properties removed from BuildConfig class in library projects.

Release note for [Android plugin 4.1.0 reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior_changes)

In case, If your library needs the version name for some reference in your library, you can add a custom attribute inside your **buildType** or **flavor**

For example, in **buildTypes** you can add like this

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION_NAME", "\"6.8.0\""
    }
}
```

where ***6.8.0*** is the version name.